# Force to do flush to get new Primary key ID to store EmbeddedId

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

We are using `JPA` and we are using `EmbeddedId` in one of the `Entity`.

Tables are as bellow :

```
Role:
+-----------------------------+
| roleId | name | discription |
+-----------------------------+


Rights:
+-----------------------------+
| rightId | name | discription|
+-----------------------------+

rightrole
+--------------------------------------+
| roleId | rightId | some other column |
+--------------------------------------+
```

**Entity for role table is:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long roleID;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "role", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RightRole> rightRoleList;

.......
}
```

**Entity for rightrole table is:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "rightrole")
    public class RightRole extends BaseEntity<RightRolePK> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @EmbeddedId
        protected RightRolePK rightRolePK;


        @JoinColumn(name = "roleID", referencedColumnName = "roleID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Role role;

        @JoinColumn(name = "rightID", referencedColumnName = "rightID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Right right;

        ......
     }


    @Embeddable
    public class RightRolePK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Basic(optional = false)
      @NotNull
      @Column(nullable = false)
      private long roleID;

      @Basic(optional = false)
      @NotNull
      @Column(nullable = false)
     private long rightID;

   .....

}
```

My problem is whenever I want to create new `role` with `rights` then first I have to `store(persist)` `role` object and then I have to do `flush` to get newly generated `id` for role. then and then i can put it in `rightrole` entity's object.

Is there any way by that i can set `rightrole` list in role object and persist it in one go.

This flush casing us performance bottle neck because for bulk insert we have to persist single single object.

we are using `Auto Generated` primary key.

Comment: Use a different strategy for Role? like a UUID. Have an autogenerated id for RightRole instead of this hacky mess you have with compound identity?

Comment: we have around 35 tables in which we are using this compound identity so changing this require lots of code change in our existing application.

Comment: just a suggestion if you can actually get down to simplify that: use @joinTable annotation for a manyToMany relationship like that without additional column besides Ids in the rightRole table.
That would make this matter as easy as create the two object, add rights to rightList of role and persist

Comment: @Zeromus can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA 2.0 allows derived IDs, an expanded to support this better by adding [@MapsId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html).  Keeping everything else the same but using:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rightrole")
public class RightRole extends BaseEntity<RightRolePK> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected RightRolePK rightRolePK;

    @MapsId("roleID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleID", referencedColumnName = "roleID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Role role;

    @MapsId("rightID")
    @JoinColumn(name = "rightID", referencedColumnName = "rightID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Right right;

    ......
 }
```

This will tell JPA that the value within the `roleID` and `rightID` attributes in your PK class are controlled by the relationship mapping, and it will set it after synchronizing to the database with the primary key value from the reference.  You just need to be sure you set the relationship before calling persist, as it doesn't have a primary key otherwise.

This works even if the referenced object is also composite.  Something that needs to reference RightRole would use RightRolePK though instead of a Long value:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wrong_right_role")
public class WrongRightRole{
    @EmbeddedId
    WrongRightRoleId wrongRightRoleId;

    @MapsId("rightRoleID")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "roleID", referencedColumnName = "roleID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "rightID", referencedColumnName = "rightID")
    })
    RightRole rightRole;

}

@Embeddable
public class WrongRightRolePK implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private RightRoleID rightRoleID;
  .....
}
```

JPA also allows marking the `right` and `role` mappings with the `@ID` annotation, allowing you to remove the `rightRolePK embeddedId` from within the object, and use it as a primary key class instead.

Comment: I am getting this error org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.PersistenceObjectAttributeAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(PersistenceObjectAttributeAccessor.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.setAttributeValueInObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1637)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.setRealAttributeValueInObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1651)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.updateDerivedIds(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5461)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWor

Answer (score 1):

Using a @ManyToMany annotation you can define your entity like this:

Role:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "role")
    public class Role {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false)
        private Long roleID;

        @JoinTable(name = "rightrole",
                joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "roleID", referencedColumnName = "ROLE_ID")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "rightID", referencedColumnName = "RIGHT_ID")})
        @ManyToMany
        private List<Right> rightList;

    }
```

**You have to write `@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})` in `inverseJoinColumns` otherwise your parent data will get deleted if child get deleted.**

Right:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "right")
public class Right {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "RIGHT_ID",nullable = false)
    private Long rightId;

}
```

you can then simply:

```
    Role role = new  Role();
    List<Right> rightList = new ArrayList<>();
    Right right1 = new Right();
    Right right2 = new Right();
    rightList.add(right1);
    rightList.add(right2);
    role.setRightList(rightList);
```

and persist

the @JoinTable annotation will take care of inserting in the rightrole table even without an entity (as long as that table have only the id columns of role and right) so you'll get something like this in db

Role :

```
id name     etc
1  roleName etc
```

Right:

```
id name       etc
1  rightName1 etc
2  rightName2 etc
```

rightrole:

```
roleId rightID
1      1
1      2
```

Comment: if your rightrole entity was only to define the link between roleId and rightId you dont need it

Comment: You solution works only on two(parent) columns  but what if i have multiple columns in `rightrole` table.

Comment: as i already said this works only on a simple manyToMany relationship... if you have 3 table that should join together then you have to write the entity with all the manyToOne like you have been doing

Comment: your answer is helpful in some scenario so +1